# Include a stylus plugin in Vue.js project

Tags: vue.js, webpack, plugins, nib, stylus

I can't include a stylus plugin in my project, the code varies so much from one version to another that I'm lost trying everything and anything.

Here are the versions I currently have:

"nib": "^1.1.2",

"vue": "^2.5.16",

"stylus": "^0.54.5",

"stylus-loader": "^3.0.2",

```js
// vue.config.js

const nib = require('nib');

module.exports = {
    configureWebpack: {
        stylus: {
            use: [nib()],
            import: ['nib'],
        },
    },
};
```

Has anyone succeeded?

I would like to understand how to do it and why what I do doesn't work, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<s>Once I installed rupture this way using vue-cli:</s>

```
const rupture = require('rupture')

module.exports = {
  configureWebpack: {
    css: {
      loaderOptions: {
        stylus: {
          use: [rupture()]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I found the correct way to install nib:

```
module.exports = {
  css: {
    loaderOptions: {
      stylus: {
        use: [require('nib')()],
        import: ['~nib/lib/nib/index.styl']
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm getting an error:
`
 ERROR  WebpackOptionsValidationError: Invalid configuration object. Webpack has been initialised using a configuration object that does not match the API schema.
 - configuration has an unknown property 'css'. These properties are valid:
   object { amd?, bail?, cache?, context?, dependencies?, devServer?, devtool?, entry?, externals?, loader?, mode?, module?, name?, node?, optimization?, output?, parallelism?, performance?, plugins?, profile?, recordsInputPath?, recordsOutputPath?, recordsPath?, resolve?, resolveLoader?, serve?, stats?, target?, ... }
`

Comment: @Jimmy.D I updated my answer, check if it helps you.

Comment: It works ! Thank you.

But i have a lot of warning in the console because of Vuetify:

`You should write display: flex by final spec instead of display: box`

Comment: I think it's about this problem:

https://github.com/stylus/nib/issues/312

Answer (score 0):

To use Stylus, you need to configure the css loader in your webpack config, add this to rules:

```js
{
  test: /\.css$/,
  use: [
    'vue-style-loader',
    'css-loader'
  ]
}
```

And install the style-loaders:
`npm install --save-dev css-loader vue-style-loader`

The css should then load and you have css processing in both our external assets and our single-file components.

One final change here to use stylus is to install the loader:
`npm install --save-dev stylus stylus-loader`

And add a rule:

```json
{
  test: /\.styl(us)?$/,
  use: [
    'vue-style-loader',
    'css-loader',
    'stylus-loader'
  ]
}
```

Comment: Actually stylus is already functional on my project.

`<style lang="stylus">
    .mySelector
        height 100%
        width 100%
</style>`

I just want to be able to use the "nib" plugin, no matter what I do I can't make it work in the "<style lang=stylus"></style> tags of my `.vue` files.

Which would give:

`<style lang="stylus">
    .mySelector
        size 100%
</style>`

Answer (score 0):

Final solution:

In vue.config.js file

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
    css: {
        loaderOptions: {
            stylus: {
                use: [
                    require('nib')(),
                ],
                import: [
                    path.resolve(__dirname, './src/styles/nibFixes.styl'),
                    '~nib/lib/nib/index.styl',
                ],
            },
        },
    },
};
```

In ./src/styles/nibFixes.styl file

```
// To fix https://github.com/stylus/nib/issues/312

flex-version = flex
support-for-ie = false
vendor-prefixes = official
```